# Using curl on windows to extract xml content on the fly

Tags: xml, curl

I am testing a restful web service using curl (HTTP GET Methods receiving XML in response).curl fetches those xmls correctly but I want to extract the text content of a tag named **Document**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <data>    
        <Results>
            <Document>
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <Tags></Tags>
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
            </Document>
        </Results>
    </data>
```

Currently what I am doing is , loading those xmls from disc and parsing them in java to get the required inner embedded xml.
I was wondering if there exist an other simple way of fetching inner tags content **on the fly** (while receiving response) and then store final xml on disc.

This is the required format that I want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                <Document>
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <Tags></Tags>
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     .
                </Document>
                <Document>
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <Tags></Tags>
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     .
                </Document>
                <Document>
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <Tags></Tags>
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     .
                </Document>
```